# The controller name in a custom partial views location with mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views, viewengine

I followed this tutorial to customize my partial views locations.
http://www.leonamarant.com/2011/02/17/adding-a-custom-directory-to-razor-view-engine-partial-view-locations-in-asp-net-mvc3/

Everything is ok except one thing : define a custom location with a controller name.
Here is my locations :

```
private static string[] customLocations = new[] {
    "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",       // It does not work
    "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",    // It works
    "~/Views/Home/{0}.cshtml"       // It works
};
```

In my view, I just add this line and the partial view is not found  :

```
@Html.Partial("Test/_MyPartial")
```

I know that I could write a relative path to resolve my problem but this line does not require my class "MyViewEngine.cs"

```
@Html.Partial("../Test/_MyPartial")
```

How can I bind my controller name with the {1} ?

Comment: "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml" is a default location where Razor view engine looks where {1} is the controller name rit.So you dont need to define a custom location for this in you class. So also in your case @Html.Partial("_MyPartial") may works.

Comment: I know what you mean but in my case, I try to display 2 partial views from a different controller.
Imagine a MediaController with ~/Views/Media/List.cshtml and this view include 2 partial views : ~/Views/Picture/_List.cshtml and ~/Views/Video/_List.cshtml